# Can we use a Baden-Württemberg ticket from different places?

Tags: tickets, germany, buses, fares, stuttgart

My fried lives in Stuttgart, and I live in a small village called Isny im Allgäu. We are planning to travel to Konstanz together. The problem is that there is no train in my village, so I need to take two buses to reach Ravensburg city. I can wait for him to get in the train with him.

The question is while he's coming from Stuttgart, can I use the ticket which is already for two passengers to get to Ravensburg city, because the train goes from Stuttgart to Friedrichshafen through Ravensburg?

Comment: Although I understand that English might not be your native language (it is not mine either), I would ask you to please use proper grammar and punctuation when writing on this site. Honestly, correcting errors like these is tedious and boring.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I get your question right. Are you planning on both using the same ticket at the same time, but in different busses/trains? That does not work.

You should not have any issues using the ticket with less people then it is for (i.e., traveling alone on a two-person ticket). However, if you want two people to use the ticket, they have to travel together.

Comment: To add, you are allowed to have people join or leave the trip at any point provided that their names are written on the ticket at purchase time.  However, I believe that the ticket can not be used simultaneously on two different buses/trains.

Comment: I think this answer should be a comment, since it is not clear what OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

I think you are confusing two things: A bus ticket is completely different from a train ticket. There are in fact train tickets which allow for an extra fare to use the bus tickets in the destination area (z.B. SchönerTagTicket NRW), but I take an educated guess that Ravensburg as middle station is out of reach.

Please also state exactly what kind of ticket(s) do you have because there are many special tickets so your question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: "A bus ticket is completely different from a train ticket." - the crucial point is that the OP and their friend want to fork their paths while still using the same group ticket. That's not possible to my knowledge. Furthermore, your statement is not generally true - the [Baden-Württemberg-Ticket](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/angebot/regio/regionale-tickets/bawue/bawue_ticket.shtml) includes "Alle Nahverkehrszüge, Verkehrsverbünde sowie fast alle Linienbusse in Baden-Württemberg." ("all short distance trains, traffic consortiums, as well as almost all buses in B-W").

Comment: I know that there are exceptions, I even mentioned the *SchönerTagTicket NRW*. That does not change the problem that once you are outside a *Verkehrsverbund* (transport association ?), bus and train tickets are separate entities. The title was wrongly written so I had no clue that there really is a *Baden-Württemberg-Ticket* (it is still unclear if it is this ticket). I know that you are living in Baden-Württemberg, so by the way where is your better answer ? :-D

Comment: In [large parts of Germany](http://www.nahverkehr-info.de/images/karteverbund.png), you are inside a transport association that includes local railways. And various types of train tickets outside of such transport associations, or spanning several such associations, include buses one way or another, either at the destination, or all the way. In any case, I see no need for a better answer, as [mrks's answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91210/13104) already covers all the relevant points.